# Laravel 4 - ignore after filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Say I have the following route:

```
    Route::any('/door1/{options?}', array(
        'as' => 'path',
        'after' => 'somefilter',
        'uses' => 'DoorController@path'
    ))
```

where my after filter has the job to increment some value on a DB Table. The filter would look something like this:

```
    Route::filter('somefilter', function($route, $request, $response, $action)
    {
        try
        {
            //...
            IncrementDBTable();
            //...
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            return Redirect::home();
        }
    });
```

As for the controller,
if the options parameter is valid then all is fine and a specific view is called, otherwise the options are "corrected" and a redirect to the same route is performed:

```
    public function path($options='option1,option2')
    {
        if( !this->isValidOptions($options) ) {
            $options = this->correctOptions($options);
            return Redirect::route( 'path', array(
                'options' => $options
            ) );
        }

        // everything fine:
        return View::make( 'door' );
    }
```

My problem is, and for the case the options are wrong, the after filter is called twice, meaning the increment on the DB table is performed also twice. How can I "ignore" the after filter for the case the options are wrong? One possible solution of course is to also validate the options inside the filter function, but I wouldn't like to replicate code (this is just a simple example but things would get ugly if the validate options function would involve a lot more of code and possibly a bunch of db queries).

Comment: Hmm you could do the counting inside the controller so you have all control over it.

Comment: Yeah, why are you even doing this in a filter in the first place?

Comment: I guess that's what filters are for right? Let's say my filter is for incrementing the page views of a specific page/route. Let's also assume I wanna do that for the different pages of my app. Then I guess it would be much more elegant to have several after filters for the different pages/routes rather than having each controller method implementing that functionality. I am just trying to code my controllers as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you can skip the `Redirect` after correcting the options and just continue down the function instead. I don't see a reason for redirecting after correcting the options. That will also solve your problem about the `after` filter being called twice.

Comment: Yes that is true. My fault, the example I gave is too simplistic. The actual scenario I have is that the url needs to be corrected. For example if I would type www.myapp.com/Z/XPTO then my controller would redirect to www.myapp.com/X/XPTO because XPTO would fail on my validation (let's assume I have a table of pairs and the correct pair is X-XPTO and not Z-XPTO). I hope this is making sense :)

Comment: So you mean you are actually not redirecting to the ```path``` route?

Comment: Yes, I am, but with different parameters. Following the above logic I would redirect to www.myapp.com/X/XPTO from www.myapp.com/Y/XPTO (Route::any('/{match1}/{match2}')